# No overload for method 'ElemMatch' takes 7 arguments

Tags: c#, mongodb

`catlist` param is `singing,dancing`

```
string[] cat_sel = catlist.Split(',');
var andList = new List<IMongoQuery>();
foreach (var attribute in cat_sel)
{
   andList.Add(Query.Matches("talentinfo.type", attribute));
}

IMongoQuery query = Query.And(
       Query.EQ("enable", true),
       Query.EQ("type", "member")

);
IMongoFields fields = Fields.Include("_id", "name", "thumbnail").ElemMatch("memberinfo", Query.And(
            Query.EQ("status", "approved")),
            Query.GTE("height", 160),
            Query.LTE("height", 170),
            Query.GTE("weight", 55),
            Query.LTE("weight", 65),
            Query.And(Query.Or(andList))
            );
MongoCursor mongocursor = nsdb.GetCollection(DBPrefix, "Member").Find(query).SetFields(fields);
```

I got the error `No overload for method 'ElemMatch' takes 7 arguments`, mean I take too many argument, but I must keep those `Query` , How can I apply more `Query` for `ElemMtach` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have not closed the parenthesis properly.

Try this.

```
IMongoFields fields = Fields.Include("_id", "name", "thumbnail").ElemMatch("memberinfo", 
        Query.And(
            Query.EQ("status", "approved"),
            Query.GTE("height", 160),
            Query.LTE("height", 170),
            Query.GTE("weight", 55),
            Query.LTE("weight", 65),
            Query.And(Query.Or(andList)))
 );
```